# In C, is it possible to read a char from getchar's current buffer position without moving the buffer's pointer?

Tags: c, buffer, stdin, getchar

I have a file that's been passed as stdin in my program. Every iteration of a very large loop, a method "get_next" calls getchar, and gets the next char in stdin and assigns it to a variable named nchar.

The problem is, I have an instance where I have to look at the char after the current nchar without changing what the next call to get_next does. Meaning, I have to call getchar() without it changing the buffer's state.

Is there a way to do this? Is there a method like "getcharStatic" that returns the next char without changing the buffer, à la peek vs pop for a stack?

Alternatively, is there a way to read the char normally with getchar and then insert the char right where I took it from, thereby artificially conserving the buffer's state?

I tried googling for a while, and I think the problem involves too vague terms and tags. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ungetc()` to push the character back into stdin. Here's a blurb from the [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ungetc):

```
int ungetc( int ch, FILE *stream );
```

> If ch does not equal EOF, pushes the character ch (reinterpreted as unsigned char) into the input
>   buffer associated with the stream stream in such a manner that
>   subsequent read operation from stream will retrieve that character.

Comment: And the state of the steam passed in ungetc()'s parameter is conserved from getchar's?

Like, as I call ungetc(nchar, stdin) it should put it right where getchar now points, making nchar the next char returned by the next getchar call?

Thank you very much for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ungetc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ungetc.html), maybe like this:

```
int fpeekc(FILE *fp)
{
    int c = getc(fp);
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetc(c, fp);
    return c;
}
```

Careful reading of the POSIX specification indicates that you could call `ungetc()` with EOF and the call would be ignored, so it isn't 100% necessary to make the test in the `fpeekc()` function, but it does make `ungetc()` fail and return EOF.  If you like living — dangerously, or compactly; take your choice — you could use:

```
int fpeekc(FILE *fp)
{
    return ungetc(getc(fp), fp);
}
```

And if you desired, you could make that an inline function.  If you are on POSIX and need to be thread-safe, you can use:

```
int fpeekc(FILE *fp)
{
    flockfile(fp);
    int c = getc_unlocked(fp);  // Legitimate because of flockfile(); getc(fp) works too
    if (c != EOF)
    {
        // ungetc_unlocked() is not defined by POSIX but is available on
        // some but not all POSIX-like systems.  See comments below.
        ungetc(c, fp);
    }
    funlockfile(fp);
    return c;
}
```

That prevents another thread from interfering with the stream while you're working on it.  See also the discussion with [Nominal Animal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475978/nominal-animal) in the comments below.

And you could use:

```
static inline int peekc(void) { return fpeekc(stdin); }
```

if you want to do it for standard input.

Comment: Perhaps `int c = getc_unlocked(fp); if (c != EOF) ungetc_unlocked(c, fp);` in the POSIX thread-safe version?

Comment: In the POSIX environment, `getc_unlocked()` would be sensible, but [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) doesn't define an `ungetc_unlocked()` so that becomes something of a portability issue, for all it's an obvious function to also implement.  In the rationale section of [`getc_unlocked()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getc_unlocked.html) it says: _The `ungetc()` function is infrequently called relative to the other functions/macros so no unlocked variation is needed._  Irksome in this context, but not wholly unreasonable.

Comment: Oh; I didn't notice that; good point. (In practice, `ungetc_unlocked()` does seem to exist on all POSIXy systems I know of, even on HP-UX. Hopefully this gets eventually fixed in POSIX.1...)

Comment: It's interesting that HP-UX has it! Running `man ungetc_unlocked` on macOS 10.14 Mojave yields "No manual entry for ungetc_unlocked" — but there is an entry OK for `getc_unlocked`.  So, there's a counter-example, and presumably other BSD-based systems would have the same issue.  Not insoluble, but some systems would need to change.

Comment: That is surprising! Could you check if it is provided in macOS 10.14 C library, just missing from the man page?  FreeBSD [implements](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/12/lib/libc/stdio/ungetc.c?view=markup) it as `_ungetc()`, but I'm not sure if it is exported.

Comment: Nope; `ungetc_unlocked()` is not present in the macOS 10.14 Mojave C library (linker error: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ungetc_unlocked", referenced from:
      _fpeekc in cccyckLg.o`).  A recursive `grep` on `/usr/include` finds `feof_unlocked(p)`,
`ferror_unlocked(p)`,
`clearerr_unlocked(p)`,
`fileno_unlocked(p)` — which surprises me — but not `ungetc_unlocked`.  I had to suppress my normal warning options since the code would not normally compile because `ungetc_unlocked()` is not declared either.

Comment: Does it work if you `#define ungetc_unlocked _ungetc`?

Comment: Nope: no joy there either.  `_ungetc()` isn't declared, and when the warnings are overridden, there's no symbol `__ungetc` (the system adds a leading underscore to all externally visible symbols – see `_ungetc_unlocked` in a previous comment).  Poking around `/usr/include/stdio.h` finds things like `#define getc_unlocked(fp)   __sgetc(fp)` (where `__sgetc` is a macro or inline function) but there's nothing analogous for `ungetc`, let alone `ungetc_unlocked`.

Comment: Since `ungetc()` is a full function call (on macOS 10.14), the `if (c != EOF)` test saves function call overhead, which might be significant.

Comment: Thank you for the investigation! So, it looks like the proper response to my initial comment is *"Perhaps not. It works on some POSIXy systems, but not all."* Also, man7's [man unlocked_stdio](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/unlocked_stdio.3.html) comments that *"`_unlocked()` variants should probably not be used"*. Teaches me to do better research before commenting... Apologies for the noise.

Comment: Using `getc_unlocked()` after the `flockfile()` is legitimate — but it would probably be a small performance benefit. I'd forgotten it; your suggestion is helpful. That `ungetc_unlocked()` is not part of POSIX was something I'd never checked. This is a context where, if it was universally available, it would be legitimate to use it. When it's not available, it's probably best to fall back on `ungetc()` and accept the (small) overhead: `#ifndef ungetc_unlocked` / `#define ungetc_unlocked(c, fp) ungetc(c, fp)` / `#endif`.  Thanks for the disucssion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `int ungetc(int char, FILE *stream)`.
You could have a method:

```
char fgetputbackc(file *f){
    int c = fgetc(f);
    ungetc(c, f);
    return c;
}
```